# Physics EMF symbol in LaTeX

Tags: greek

How does one create the symbol for EMF (electromotive force) used in physics for a LaTeX document? It is like `\varepsilon` but uppercased.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @hftf I'm not sure this really should be a duplicate, because the symbol used for EMF is `\mathcal{E}` (I've written it many times, I know), but the other question's poster specifically says that is not the symbol they're looking for.

Comment: @DavidZ I've never seen it written `\mathcal{E}`.

Comment: @hftf well, now you have, or at least you know someone who has. ;-) I guess there must be some variation between sources, but pretty much every time I remember seeing it, the symbol seems like an exact match to the calligraphic E.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this close enough?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[\mathcal{E} \varepsilon \]
\end{document}
```

[image]