# Is it possible to get the LaTeX command for special symbol, like J calligraphic with bar in the middle

Tags: fonts, equations, symbols, physics

how to make the latex command for this symbol [image: J bar]

Comment: Did you check this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239535/physics-emf-symbol-in-latex comments?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that what you call a "special J with bar in the middle" is actually an "F".

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=esstix]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{E \quad F \quad H \quad M}$ 
\end{document}
```